# Gmpy sqrt precision

Tags: python, sqrt

I want to know why does this code in Python

```
print gmpy.sqrt(2009)
```

give the result 44, and not 44.82186966... like i want it to do? How can i set the function to show me the decimal numbers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bluntly put, because it was defined that way. There is no way to set that option.

Edit: @casevh is correct: `gmpy2.sqrt()` returns what you want.

Comment: gmpy supports the GMP library. And the GMP library has limited support for floating point numbers. The sqrt() function in GMP is only defined for integers. gmpy2 supports the MPFR (floating point) and MPC (complex) libraries in addition to GMP. In gmpy2, the sqrt() function now returns an mpfr (floating point) or mpc (complex) result. The integer functions were renamed to begin with an "i".

Comment: @Aksiom Please note that my answer has changed.